# Python shutil.copytree() is there away to track the status of the copying

Tags: python, copy

I have a lot of raster files (600+) in directories that I need copy into a new location (including their directory structure). Is there a way to track the status of the copying using shutil.copytree()? Normally with files I would use the code below, but not sure how to do the same with shutil.copytree():

```
for currentFolder, subFolder, fileNames in os.walk(sourceFolder):
   for i in fileNames:
        if i.endswith(".img"):
            print "copying {}".format(i)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(currentFolder,i), outPutFolder)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, something like this is possible by taking advantage of the function name passed in for 'ignore' parameter. In fact something like this is given in the example section of python docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#copytree-example

Example pasted below as well:

```
from shutil import copytree
import logging

def _logpath(path, names):
    logging.info('Working in %s' % path)
    return []   # nothing will be ignored

copytree(source, destination, ignore=_logpath)
```

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use the `copy_function` argument of `copytree`. The advantage is that it will be called for every file that is copied instead of each folder.

```
from shutil import copytree,copy2

def copy2_verbose(src, dst):
    print('Copying {0}'.format(src))
    copy2(src,dst)

copytree(source, destination, copy_function=copy2_verbose)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2.7**

The source code for `shutil` from Python 2.7 can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py).  You should be able to copy the source code, then add `print name` to line 282.

**Python 3.4**

The source code for `shutil` from Python 3.4 can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/shutil.py).  You should be able to copy the source code, then add `print name` to line 307.

Comment: For anyone looking, Python 3.6 and higher can be [found on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/shutil.py).