# PyCharm console not printing in the same line, but does in debug console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ipython

I want to show a progress bar in PyCharm, but the console doesn't seem to be printing on the same line. Weird thing is that if I run the code in debug mode, the debug console works properly, printing the progress bar in the same line). Here's the code snippet for the progress bar ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524422)):

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r{0}".format(str(i)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'd appreciate if you could help me identify what's wrong with the console.