# Is there some sort of way to track the progress of shutil.make_archive()?

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I am making a script that compresses folders via `shutil.make_archive`, but the folders can be large, so it will take a while. Is there some sort of way I can show the percentage complete? So far I have been checking out the `threading` module, but I haven't found much yet

Here is an example of what I want the output to be:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$./script foldername
Compressing foldername.zip (15%)
```

Here is my code so far:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import sys
folderName = sys.argv[1]
percent = #I don't know what to put here
shutil.make_archive("{0} Compressed".format(folderName), "zip", folderName)
print("Compressing {0}.zip ({1})".format(folderName, percent), end="\r")
```

You can make any changes you need to make it work

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967487/get-progress-back-from-shutil-file-copy-thread

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to track the progress of `shutil.make_archive()` but by combining tqdm and zipfile, one can achieve the expected result. Here is a snippet doing that:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import zipfile

zip_file_path = "/tmp/tmp.zip"
local_path = # Whatever file or directory you wand to compress

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, mode="w") as archive:
    for file_path in tqdm(list(Path(local_path).rglob("*")), desc='Adding to Zip '):
        archive.write(
            file_path,
            arcname=file_path.relative_to(local_path)
        )
```

The end result looks like that:
[image]